# Travis determine which files changed

Tags: git, travis-ci

I have a Travis script that runs for every push.

I need to determine which files were modified in this push.

Currently, I have this:

`CHANGED_FILES=($(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1))`

The problem is that sometimes a push can include more than one commits, and this only looks at the last commit.

What is the expected way to solve this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found out there is a Travis environment variable: `$TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE`.

Then it was only a matter of changing the script to:

`CHANGED_FILES=($(git diff --name-only $TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE))`

Comment: Are you sure that `git diff $TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE` will show the first commit's diff too?